# Notepad++ replacing all numbers after a certain string

Tags: notepad++

After opening a config file for a game, I notice there is strength 5 strength and the '5' can be any random number. How do I replace every number after the word "strength" to a 1?

Comment: What is exact format? Paste the exact format of how it is in the file

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are your friends, even when they can be your enemies if misused.
You want to do a search and replace with Regex enabled.
Search:
(strength)(\d+)(strength)
Replace:
\11\2